# How to query Elasticsearch to compare most recent nested element?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am hoping to get some help with a specific ES query I have not been able to figure out (ES 7.10). I have an index with a few fields and a nested array and I want to be able to find the documents where the "value" field is not the same as the most recent value field in the array. Assuming I have the documents below.

```
{
   "id": 123
   "value": "A",
   "updates": [
      {"value": "B", "date": "2023-04-12T01:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": "C", "date": "2023-04-13T01:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": "A", "date": "2023-04-14T01:00:00.000Z"}      
   ]
}
```

```
{
   "id": 456
   "value": "A"
   "updates": [
      {"value": "A", "date": "2023-04-12T01:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": "B", "date": "2023-04-13T01:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": "C", "date": "2023-04-14T01:00:00.000Z"}      
   ]
}
```

I would want the query to return only 456 since the value "A" does not equal the value in the most recent update for that document.

Thanks in advance for your time!

I have tried slicing this problem a number of different ways. This is my most recent attempt to get the latest nested value and compare to the other value but I am getting an aggregation exception. Perhaps this is not the best approach anyway.

```
`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "updates",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "updates.value.keyword": {
                  "value": "most_recent_status"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "max_value": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "updates"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "updates.date"
          }
        },
        "last_status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "updates.value.keyword",
            "size": 1,
            "order": {
              "max_date": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

```
"type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
"reason" : "Invalid aggregation order path [max_date]. The provided aggregation [max_date] either does not exist, or is a pipeline aggregation and cannot be used to sort the buckets.
```